# How to use the Java Version of Alexa ASK 2 DialogeStage and Delegate?

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to work with Alexa's ASK 2.7.1 Java version.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
  <artifactId>ask-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The following code seems to successfully delegate back to Alexa for a missing slot.

```
@Override
public Optional<Response> handle(HandlerInput input) {
   Request request = input.getRequestEnvelope().getRequest();
   IntentRequest intentRequest = (IntentRequest) request;
   Intent intent = intentRequest.getIntent();
   return input.getResponseBuilder().addDelegateDirective(intent).build();
}
```

However, I have not been able to then handle the intent when all of the slots are given. For example trying to return the following has been failing, with error, after delegation.

```
return input.getResponseBuilder()
            .withSpeech(speechText)
            .withReprompt(repromptText)
            .build();
```

Looking at the official JavaScript samples it seems I need to make two classes. One to delegate and one to send the speech. But, when I try to do something akin to `intentRequest.getDialogState().equals(DialogState.COMPLETED)` in the 'canHandle' or 'handle' method I get a NullPointerException.

The official Java samples do not show how to do this. Do you have a working Java delegation example? Or can point me in the right direction?